# How do the find the version number of a library if it got deleted in the JS file?

Tags: javascript, version

Is there a way to see the current version of the below libraries without looking at the info usually found in the js file? My info got deleted. I know in jquery-atmosphere you can use `jQuery.atmosphere.version` in the console to return its version, but I can't seem to find it from the below libraries:

- html5lightbox
- async
- jquery.scrollintoview
- moment-locales
- nprogress
- underscore
- bootstrap-datepicker
- bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: `npm ls` will list you your dependencies (if you installed them with npm)

Comment: i didn't but that's good to know in the future